# using java from FreeBSD

Tags: java, freebsd

I installed the openjdk on freebsd 9.0 RC2 as advised [here](http://www.freebsd.org/java/install.html). It was a bit slow, but it seemed to complete successfully.  Now when I type:

```
mammalucco# java myjar.jar nogui
java: command not found
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Did you verify that the port installed correctly? Did you do `locate java`?

If `locate` does not find it, it's probably not built or installed correctly. If locate comes back with something, make sure that the directory containing `java` is in your `PATH`.